# How to install pyinstaller using pip

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to install PyInstaller using pip but i am failing in doing so. I have Python 2.7.

Error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pyinstaller
Downloading/unpacking pyinstaller
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyinstaller
No distributions at all found for pyinstaller
Storing complete log in C:\Users\hardik\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

I tried upgrading pip first with `pip install -U pip setuptools` but got the same error:

```
C:\Users\hardik>pip install -U pip setuptools
Cannot fetch index base URL pypi.python.org/simple
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in c:\python27\lib \site-packages
No distributions at all found for pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Storing complete log in C:\Users\hardik\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and this is how I solved it:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```