# Installing pyinstaller via pip leads to "failed to create process"

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip, anaconda, pyinstaller

Does anyone know why `pyinstaller` immediately fails after installed via `pip` via `anaconda 32bit`?

I installed pyinstaller via `pip install pyinstaller` through the anaconda command prompt on Windows 64 bit using 32 bit anaconda (because I want to create 32 bit executables)

Yes I read [pyinstaller --version failed to create a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620172/pyinstaller-version-failed-to-create-a-process) and [pip/easy_install failure: failed to create process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373265/pip-easy-install-failure-failed-to-create-process) and [How to install pyinstaller using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069451/how-to-install-pyinstaller-using-pip)

I did not rename any files I installed anaconda 15 mins ago, pycharm 10 mins ago, and pyinstaller 5 mins ago. I uninstalled pyinstaller via pup uninstall and reinstalled in the anaconda scripts folder, this did nothing.

Any insight anyone? #windowsfrustrations
Path
`C:\Users\me\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages>PyInstaller`

Comment: Was your user really `me` or did you have a real user name that had a space?  (e.g. `John Doe`)

Comment: This has been fixed as of July 2016

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Update: So apparently the root fix for this is in setuptools. The fix went into setuptools version 24.3.1 released July 23, 2016. Upgrading to anything newer than that should take care of this.]

It turns out this is a [bug in pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2783). As mentioned in the other answer it has a problem with spaces in the path to the python install.

Specifically it leaves out quote marks in the generated launcher scripts. The scripts can be found in \Scripts\ (e.g. C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts). For pyinstaller there 4 pyi-* and a pyinstaller-script.py scripts.

You can work around this relatively easily by editing the first line of each script. The generated first lines will look something like:

```
#!c:\program files\python 3.5\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'PyInstaller==3.1.1','console_scripts','pyinstaller'
```

Just add quotes around the shebang command, like so:

```
#!"c:\program files\python 3.5\python.exe"
```

Comment: It's been a year since the original question was asked, and this answer still worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: the sentence "For pyinstaller there 4 pyi-* and a pyinstaller-script.py scripts." is so misleading. in fact just changing the  pyinstaller-script.py file worked, thanks anway

Comment: This bug appears to be fixed in later pip and setuptools. See [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39045803/694733) how to fix it instead.

Answer (score 8):

This error seems to occur when Python’s (or PyInstaller’s) path contains a space (for example, when one installs Python to the `Program Files (x86)` directory.)

I suspect that somewhere in PyInstaller’s source code there are some missing quotation marks.

Try installing Python in a path without spaces, and installing PyInstaller (via pip) to that path.

Comment: I reinstalled python without spaces. This looks like a better option than editing all the launcher scripts. You may loose your changes when you upgrade pyinstaller.

Answer (score 6):

As StationaryTraveller mentioned, you can work around this bug by calling script `pyinstaller-script.py`

Below is an example

```
C:>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py" script_to_compile.py
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

As of July 2016 the issue was reported as fixed, ugrading pip, setuptools and then uninstalling and installing pyinstaller should remedy the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, even with pip and setuptools updated, and the problem was that pyinstaller-script.py, found in C:\Python35\Scripts\ directory, had the wrong path for python.exe.

Python on my system was somehow installed in AppData, but its' scripts and modules were being installed in C:\Python35\ folder.

Changing the first line of pyinstaller-script.py to the correct path of python.exe (Programs directory inside AppData), with quotes if there's any space in the folders' names inbetween, and it should work and no longer show the "Failed to create process".
Example:

```
#!C:\Program" "Files" "(x86)\Python\python.exe
```

Using Windows10 and Python35 official installer got Python installed there somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it [Anaconda 3.4] by doing this:

1. Enter **Anaconda Command Prompt**
2. Get to anaconda scripts folder by: **cd /path/to/anaconda/Scripts**
3. Write: **python pyinstaller-script.py path/YourScript.py**

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files\Python35-32\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py" --onefile --windowed ex_btn.py

--onefile : create only exe,
--windowed : exclude the prompting CMD,
ex_btn.py : python script file.

This worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip install pip` worked for me.

With Anaconda version of Python 3.5.2 and 3.6.0(Upgraded for this error, but the error appears to be the same with both versions), I had encountered the same error message with command `pip install pip`, or `pip install whatever`/ `conda install whatever`.

I had both Python 2.7 and 3.5, but `pip install --upgrade pip` had been working every day, until a few days ago.

Comment: It might be swapped order for 2 Python versions in the `PATH`?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I uninstall and install pyinstaller, then every things work well.

It may relate to any changes within python after installation, so re-installing is a good choice.

**uninstall:**

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

**install:**

```
pip install pyinstaller
```