# Trying to make an .exe with pyinstaller, am I doing this correctly?

Tags: python, exe, python-3.5

I need to make a script.py to be an executable file.

I researched around for a little bit and found that in order to do that on a 3.5 python script I had to install `pyinstaller` and type a line like this into the command prompt:

```
pyinstaller --onefile guiFileOpener_1_1.pyw
```

But when I did this, I got this error message:

```
failed to create process
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pyinstaller via pip leads to "failed to create process"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808180/installing-pyinstaller-via-pip-leads-to-failed-to-create-process)

Comment: Yeah I dont think this link is the same problem I am not dealing with anaconda I have a windows machine..

Comment: @gokublack it doesn't look like the same question, but the solution does sound like it might be the same for you.