# PyInstaller and Python3.6 - Tuple Index

Tags: python, executable, py2exe, pyinstaller

I wrote a little Python program and most of the people who are going to run it will be Windows users. I tried to use pyinstaller and py2exe on 2 different devices, one with Windows and the other with arch-linux.

I reinstalled it more than once, using the pip3 install pyinstaller --no-cache

I always get the same error:

```
    sudo pyinstaller --windowed --onefile test.py
49 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2
49 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
50 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.8.13-1-ARCH-x86_64-with-arch
51 INFO: wrote /home/XXXXX/test.spec
52 INFO: UPX is not available.
53 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/XXXXX', '/home/XXXXX']
54 INFO: checking Analysis
54 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
54 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
57 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
58 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 178, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
    excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 906, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 990, in _find_head_package
    q = self._safe_import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1211, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1295, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1460, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode_stores(co, m)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1505, in _scan_bytecode_stores
    name = co.co_names[oparg]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

So, in that case, I just used a testscript containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python3.6
print("hello world")
```

to make sure there is no problem with the imports and so on.

Comment: Looks like "Python 3.6 is not supported yet." https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2286

Comment: Well, thanks for the fast answer. Sadly, on my Windows machine it failes to create a process when i type pyinstaller.exe to the cmd. I'll try to get this fixed, there seems to be a solution here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808180/installing-pyinstaller-via-pip-leads-to-failed-to-create-process

Answer (score 4):

Pyinstaller doesn't support Python 3,6 yet.
You could revert to Python 3.5, or try the cx_Freeze solution mentioned ... not sure what it does though, I think it replaces it.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem with python 3.6 and pyinstaller, and have used for the first time `cx_Freeze`. It worked like a charm!

Setup.py contents:

```
import cx_Freeze
exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("downloads_folder.py")]
cx_Freeze.setup( name = "downloads",
                version = "1.0",
                options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["errno", "os", "re", "stat", "subprocess","collections","pprint","shutil", "humanize","pycallgraph"], "include_files": []}},
                executables = exe)
```

Start cmd in the directory where `setup.py` is, and run the following command: **python setup.py build**.

The executable will be found in the build directory created by cx_Freeze run.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, i m also new and got the same problem as you. I was stuck about 6 hours and tried everything. Finally i also installed cx_freeze and it worked

> pip install cx_freeze