# "failed to create process" error when using pip to install jupyter

Tags: pip

I tried installing jupyter notebook with pip, but it is showing the error "failed to create process":

```
C:\Users\user>pip install jupyter
failed to create process.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please put your error details as text in your question, not with an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pyinstaller via pip leads to "failed to create process"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808180/installing-pyinstaller-via-pip-leads-to-failed-to-create-process)