# py to exe file cant open the exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

today when i'm trying to convert my py file to exe file it shows this on the output then my exe wont work and i think this is the reason that caused my exe cant work , the py file is working normaly but the exe are not,this is my first time to get this error,yesterday i can still convert other py file to exe and working normaly

```
357023 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom35.dll
357028 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom35.dll
357029 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom35.dll
357031 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom35.dll
357034 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom35.dll
357050 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll
357057 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll
357059 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll
357060 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll
357061 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll
357063 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll
357076 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357078 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357079 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357083 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357084 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357086 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357087 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357089 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357090 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
357098 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
357105 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
357106 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
357117 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\select.pyd
357121 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
357127 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
357128 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
357130 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
357131 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
357145 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357147 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357148 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357149 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357157 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357158 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357160 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357161 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357162 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357167 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
357174 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
357175 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
357180 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
357184 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
357185 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
357187 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
357188 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
357199 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
357203 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
357208 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
357213 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
357223 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
357227 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_socket.pyd
357232 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_socket.pyd
357240 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32trace.pyd
357247 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32trace.pyd
357268 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
357270 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
357274 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
357276 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
357277 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
357286 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
357294 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\_win32sysloader.pyd
357302 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32wnet.pyd
357309 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32wnet.pyd
357310 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32wnet.pyd
357318 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32comext\shell\shell.pyd
357326 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32comext\shell\shell.pyd
357330 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32comext\shell\shell.pyd
357335 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
357340 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
357341 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
357346 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
357352 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
357354 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
357362 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357366 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357368 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357369 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357375 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357380 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357382 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357383 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357385 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357386 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357387 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357389 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357390 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357395 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pdh.pyd
357399 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pdh.pyd
357400 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pdh.pyd
357409 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357410 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357417 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_sfc64.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357425 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_philox.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357432 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pcg64.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357440 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_mt19937.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357441 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_mt19937.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357449 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_bit_generator.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357455 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_generator.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357459 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_generator.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357460 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_generator.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357462 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_generator.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357467 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_bounded_integers.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357472 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_bounded_integers.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357473 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_bounded_integers.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357481 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_common.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357486 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\_pocketfft_internal.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357490 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\_pocketfft_internal.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357492 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\_pocketfft_internal.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357497 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357501 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357502 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357504 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357512 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357516 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357522 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357523 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357525 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357526 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357527 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357529 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
357604 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357608 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357614 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357615 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357620 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357655 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357657 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357658 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357660 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357671 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357672 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357674 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357675 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357676 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357678 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357693 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357695 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357696 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357698 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357699 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357700 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357702 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357703 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357705 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357710 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357715 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357716 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357718 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357719 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357720 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357722 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
357746 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357754 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357755 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357766 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357770 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357774 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357776 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357777 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357779 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357780 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc140u.dll
357797 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357804 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357811 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357815 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357820 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357821 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357822 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357829 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll
357842 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357850 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357851 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357855 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357860 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357861 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357862 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357864 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
357868 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
```

this is my py file

```
import schedule
import multitimer
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import time
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as numpy
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button, Label
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, os

def sr():
    output = "GoogleClassroom.mp4"
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))
    while(True):
     try:
      img = pyautogui.screenshot()
      image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
      out.write(image)
      StopIteration(0.5)
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def start():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
    pyautogui.press("f11")
    time.sleep(8)
    mouse.position(1278, 566)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    print("自動加入")
    timer.start()
def stop():
    timer.stop()
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit()
def anti():
    mouse.position = (894, 184)
    time.sleep(8)
    mouse,posistion(1278, 566)
    mouse.slick(Button.left, 1)

verson = 1.0
mouse = Controller()
url ="https://meet.google.com/nuw-xahw-zht?authuser=1"
schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(start)
schedule.every().day.at("08:59").do(sr)
schedule.every().day.at("11:48").do(stop)

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("title")
win.geometry("600x500+565+250")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.config(bg="skyblue")
win.attributes("-alpha", 1)
win.attributes("-topmost", 0)

lb1 = Label(text="目前設定:")
lb1.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb1.config(bg="skyblue")
lb1.place(x=0, y=0)

lb2 = Label(text="09:00進入網頁")
lb2.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb2.config(bg="skyblue")
lb2.place(x=0, y=30)

lb3 = Label(text="11:46退出網頁")
lb3.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb3.config(bg="skyblue")
lb3.place(x=0, y=60)

lb4 = Label(text="網頁=" + url)
lb4.config(font=("Courier", 14))
lb4.config(bg="skyblue")
lb4.place(x=0, y=90)

lb5 = Label(text="每15分鐘進行防踢出")
lb5.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb5.config(bg="skyblue")
lb5.place(x=0, y=120)

lb6 = Label(text="注意事項:")
lb6.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb6.config(bg="skyblue")
lb6.place(x=0, y=350)

lb7 = Label(text="2.螢幕會錄影(只有影像沒有音源, 錄影fps視乎電腦運行速度)")
lb7.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb7.config(bg="skyblue")
lb7.place(x=0, y=410)

lb8 = Label(text="3.在程式執行時不要進行任何操作(例如:移動鼠標)")
lb8.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb8.config(bg="skyblue")
lb8.place(x=0, y=440)

lb9 = Label(text="4.請事先登入至學校帳戶")
lb9.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb9.config(bg="skyblue")
lb9.place(x=0, y=470)

lb10 = Label(text="程式會在11:47時自動關閉")
lb10.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb10.config(bg="skyblue")
lb10.place(x=0, y=150)

lb11 = Label(text="1.舊的影片會被新的影片取代(需手動取出舊的影片)")
lb11.config(font=("Courier", 15))
lb11.config(bg="skyblue")
lb11.place(x=0, y=380)

versonl = Label(text=verson)
versonl.config(bg="skyblue")
versonl.config(font=("Courier", 8))
versonl.place(x=570, y=480)

win.mainloop()
timer = multitimer.MultiTimer(interval=900, function=anti, count=-1, runonstart=False)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The `py2exe` project ran out of steam at Python 3.4. The latest version on PyPI is from October 2014. Consider using PyInstaller instead. It explicitly supports Python 3.5 and maintenance is active.

Comment: i try it out but still donest work , when i type "pyinstaller -D GC.py" it said failed to create process

Comment: Converting a Python program to an .exe is a much more complicated process than compiling some C source. The PyInstaller project has extensive documentation on what to do when things go wrong: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: Your *failed to create process* problem already has an answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808180/installing-pyinstaller-via-pip-leads-to-failed-to-create-process -- it is specifically a Python 3.5 fix, which looks like what you need.

Comment: I agree with @BoarGules. It isn't a trivial thing, which means we need far more information from you, after you've done some debugging yourself.